# Jmeter-server hanging on linux system

Tags: linux, jmeter, performance-testing

When I try and run jmeter-server from a server connected via putty, it hangs with:

```
bash-3.2$ ./jmeter-server -t filename.jmx
Using local port: 4000
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[172.31.120.200:4000]    (local),objID:[1a15acdf:12f949f58d8:-7fff, -8305458059461378367]]]
```

What am I doing wrong? It just hangs. Previously it was erroring with:

```
bash-3.2$ ./jmeter-server
Using local port: 4000
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[172.31.120.200:4000](local),objID:[1fa5aea9:12f94a578a6:-7fff, -8358825329658872549]]]
Problem creating registry: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use
Continuing...
Server failed to start: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start. See server log file.
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Port 1099 is default port of jmeter server, this means that you have already lauched jmeter server. I think you should first kill it and then try to start:

```
ps ax | grep jmeter

kill -9 PID (from previous command)
```

Before starting remote testing I think you should read documentation, seems you are doing it wrong: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Looks you need change your jmeter SERVER_PORT to a not "1099" number from the error information.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I probably were in your situation.

It helps to me to use java8 and the next properties when starting jmeter-server

```
/opt/jmeter/bin/jmeter-server \
-Dserver.rmi.localport=50000 \
-Dserver_port=1099 \
-Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

Also check logs in jmeter-server.log file